# Include add_post_meta in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta

I am trying to call  `add_post_meta()` from a plugin I have created. The plugin acts as a payment gateway for WooCommerce. This all works fine however I need to fire off the `add_post_meta()` at the end but all I get is:

> fatal error: Call to undefined function add_post_meta() in...

How would I include this function in my plugin?

Comment: Please be more specific regarding: "at the end" and add the relevant code snippet. I guess you're not running it inside any hook?

Comment: Hi, sorry by 'at the end' I just meant when I run the code. It's not in a hook no, is it possible to just include the function outside of any wordpress hooks?

Comment: I just tested calling `add_post_meta()` directly from a plugin file, not within any action callback, and got no errors. So I wonder if your setup is different? Looks like WordPress doesn't know about your plugin file. Is it activated?

Comment: Hi, I'm calling it from a php file called from an ajax request, could that be the problem?

Comment: I guess you're not using the WordPress way of doing ajax, i.e. a request through `admin-ajax.php` where your code is wrapped in a `wp_ajax_*` or a `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` action callback. Did you check this Codex page: [Ajax in plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? I think your custom ajax file  is not aware of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the callback function name for example

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'new_metabox_save',35 );
```

Function definiton

```
 function new_metabox_save(){

    $post = get_post( $post_id );
}
```